# Generate a spreadsheet file on iOS that is readable both by Excel and Numbers

Tags: ios, excel, spreadsheet

I need to generate a spreadsheet file on iOS that is readable both by Excel and Numbers. CSV file is not sufficient as it does not allow multiple sheets and/or formatting.

Which format would work the best? And is there a library/framework that I could use to generate a file in that format?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Google docs spreadsheet the [Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).  Then you can import that into Excel/Numbers.